# Limit File Uploads To One File - PHP

Tags: php, file, file-upload, limit

I have a file input element that is used to upload a profile image to a user profile page. By default browsers only allow this element to upload one file unless you add the `multiple` attribute.

I'd like to set a back up in the PHP though just in case someone decides to add the 'multiple' attribute in the HTML.

I thought assigning the `$_POST` superglobal to a variable and having an if statement saying if this value is greater than 1 would be prevent this, but it doesn't?

What is the best way to approach this? I've tried various things such as the `count()` array method but can't seem to find a solution to what seems like a very simple problem?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-profile-image'])) {

    $profileImage = $_POST['submit-profile-image'];

    if (isset($profileImage)) {
        if ($profileImage > 1) {
            $error[] = "You cannot upload more than one profile image";
        }
    }
    // ALL OTHER CODE
}
```

I've also tried using the `$_FILES` superglobal and counting the instances of the `$_FILES['profile-image']`. This encounters a different problem in that it blocks more than one file upload BUT also blocks single file uploads (and I don't understand why)?

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile-image'])){
    if(count($_FILES['profile-image']) > 1){
        $error[] = "You cannot upload more than one profile image";
    }
}
```

Comment: when there is only one file, `$_FILES` is still a multi-dimensional array, that's why `count($_FILES['profile-image'])` will result in more than `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent a user sending multiple files. All you can do is defend against the possibility, and fail gracefully.

Let's assume that your HTML includes this `<form>`

```
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form_data">
  <input type='file' name='uploadFile'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

When the user selects a file and clicks `submit` the browser packs up the file and sends it, PHP unpacks the file to the server disk, and then presents the file details to your program in the `$_FILES['uploadFile']` array.

If we assume that the user edits your HTML and adds `multiple` then the browser will pack up the files and send them. PHP will unpack the first file and add its detail to `$_FILES['uploadFile']` as before. It will then unpack the second file and place its details in `$_FILES['uploadFile']`, overwriting the first file. Your program sees only one file, knows nothing of any other file, and carries on.

To get two files your user will have to change the name of the `file` input to use array syntax, so lets suppose he changes the line to

```
  <input type='file' name='uploadFile[]' multiple>
```

Now PHP unpacks the file details into a set of arrays. Instead of having `$_FILES['uploadFile']['name']` containing a string with one filename, it becomes an array of strings.

It is likely that your code, expecting a string, will choke on an array and fail in some unexpected way. You can check for this condition with

```
if (is_array($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])) {throw new Exception("Too many files");}
```

So, our user, determined to force this extra file on you now adds a second `<input>` to the form:

```
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form_data">
  <input type='file' name='uploadFile'>
  <input type='file' name='uploadFile'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

The second file overwrites the first as it has the same name. Your program is none the wiser and carries on with just one file. So the user changes the name on the second `input`:

```
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form_data">
  <input type='file' name='uploadFile'>
  <input type='file' name='uploadFileB'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

You could check for this by looking at `count($_FILES)`, but your program isn't looking for a second input, so it will ignore it anyway and carry on handling just the first file. If the user also changes the first name your program won't see any files, and if he reverses the names, your program will see just the second file and ignore the first.

Alternatively, set the PHP configuration value in PHP.INI:

```
max_file_uploads = 1;
```

If you do this, PHP will ignore the second and subsequent files. Your code will still have to deal with the naming issues. Setting this with `ini_set()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: smart to use `max_file_uploads` directive, but this will affect the whole web server unless you use a local `php.ini` in the folder (a.k.a. the working directory).

Comment: @Raptor yes it's only on this form / page I want this restriction on - there will be other pages that allow multiple uploads (although I would like those limited to 10 per upload but I'll address that when this is sorted). Can I use a php.ini the same way as .htaccess then - in the sense a directory level php.ini will override what is set in a parent directory?

Comment: This works thanks and obviously I'm not bothered if they add inputs which changes which of the images shows - it's just to prevent malicious volume uploads. I'll set `my max_file_uploads = 10` to limit the uploads on other pages. There is one thing though if I change the `throw new Exception` part to an `$errors[]` array message (I have other validations on this page), it doesn't show the error message or any of the other validation/error messages?

Comment: @ap_cornwall You'd need to add an exception handler, but there's no specific need to throw an exception at that point. It was only intended as an illustration. Handle the condition however best fits in with your code.